# Search Menu Location in odoo12

Tags: python, css, odoo-12

[image]

In some forms, the search menu stays at the top. I need to see him always. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

that is `Many2many` view, the common list doesn't have that kind of structure, if you really need it, you can try to extend the basic search view in the main structure of Odoo.